# Hello world JAX-RS WAB example not working in Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, osgi, jersey

I'm new to Jersey and I'm trying to run an example project on Glassfish 3.1.2.  The example includes a task to run tests through PAX runner using Jersey 1.12 and that all passes.  Glassfish has customized JAR files for the server and servlet and is at 1.11.  When I deploy I get the following error messages:

```
[#|2012-06-11T09:30:19.718-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.HelloWorldResource.getClichedMessage(), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.HelloWorldResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
SEVERE: Method, public java.lang.String com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.AnotherResource.getAnotherMessage(), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.samples.helloworld.AnotherResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
SEVERE: Method, public synchronized javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.geExternalGramar(javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,java.lang.String), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.
SEVERE: Method, public synchronized javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource.getWadl(javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo), annotated with GET of resource, class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlResource, is not recognized as valid resource method.|#]
```

There is also a stack trace after the error messages above:

```
[#|2012-06-11T09:30:19.719-0400|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|WebModule[/helloworld]StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1445)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1242)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2018)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.deploy(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:183)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiDeploymentRequest.execute(OSGiDeploymentRequest.java:118)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.AbstractOSGiDeployer.deploy(AbstractOSGiDeployer.java:121)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiContainer.deploy(OSGiContainer.java:154)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.deploy(JavaEEExtender.java:107)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender.access$200(JavaEEExtender.java:61)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:151)
at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.JavaEEExtender$HybridBundleTrackerCustomizer$1.call(JavaEEExtender.java:148)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Comment: Please post the code of HelloWorldResource and AnotherResource.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your app. You may like to compare it with our simple JAX-RS/OSGi sample available at: https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/trunk/fighterfish/sample/uas/simplejaxrs

Comment: This is the hello world from the Jersey's website: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e1417

Comment: I was able to get this to work eventually, not sure what made it work exactly though.  When running through the debugger, I noticed the only ResourceMethodDispatchProvider service registered was from the multipart bundle.  This made the dispatcher for the resource method null causing the method to be rejected.  For some reason the services from the server bundle were not registered.  I uninstalled all Jersey bundles except for the jersey-core/server/servlet and that made it work.  I had to re-install Glassfish for another reason and now it is working.